# How to display my <span> inside the <svg>

Tags: html, css, svg

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-svg">
        <svg class="container-border" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
          <line class="container-top" x1="20%" y1="0"></line>
          <line class="container-top-red" x1="20%" x2="30%" y1="0"></line>
          <line class="container-left" x1="0" y1="100%"></line>
          <line class="container-right" x1="100%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="75%"></line>
          <line class="container-bottom" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="100%" y2="100%"></line>
        </svg>
        <span class="container-title">About Us</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my HTML code.

I want to create a border to my div class="col-6" with svg, and after that I want a title inside the svg border.

But if, I do this, the span appears under the svg ...
I think I need some CSS code to fix it

Please help me.

Comment: Um... your `span` is under your `svg` in your code, why are you surprised that it appears under it in the result?

Comment: But nothing Changes when I put it inside the svg

Comment: You can't just dump arbitrary HTML inside an SVG.  Either use [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), or use the obvious css positioning rules to overlap one atop the other.

Comment: ohh, I am an idiot... yes, you are right!!! thank you so much!!! And so sorry, because of this stupid question.